# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a touch event using Selenium. First time doing it. This is my code:

```
   public void getarrowright() throws Exception {
    new AccessibilityPage(driver).getdragmeframe();
    BrowserUtils.waitForVisibility(rightarrow,30,driver);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(rightarrow).click().perform();
    TouchActions tapAction = new TouchActions(driver).singleTap(rightarrow);
    tapAction.perform();
}
```

I am getting that as an error. This is how my driver page looks like:

```
case "firefox":
                caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

                FirefoxOptions ffOpts = new FirefoxOptions();
                FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

                ffProfile.setPreference("browser.autofocus", true);
                ffProfile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);

                caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, ffProfile);
                caps.setCapability("marionette", true);

                // then pass them to the local WebDriver
                if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/main/resources/Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                    webDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver(ffOpts.addCapabilities(caps)));
                }

                break;
```

Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: You should 1 - provide the full stacktrace, 2 - show us the line where the exception  happened exactly (with some surrounding code)

Answer (score 1):

Access to touch screen capabilities is an optional feature. Driver implementations that support this feature  implement the HasTouchScreen interface. According to  Javadoc, ChromeDriver is so far the only implementation that implements this interface:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasTouchScreen.html

Comment: That package was already imported but somehow its still showing the same error. :(

Comment: The class FirefoxDriver does not implement the HasTouchScreen interface. Importing the package will not change this.  Either don't use TouchActions in combination with FirefoxDriver or switch to ChromeDriver.

Comment: I tried with chrome as well, it is coming as unhandled command exception.

Comment: Switching to ChromeDriver requires more than just switching the Java class. You need a chromedriver native executable and a compatible browser. See the following page for more information: https://chromedriver.chromium.org